# Passing Value from function to class level variable always null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I defined a string variable at class level and set this variable in  `protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` after uploading the file successfully.

I do this so that i can pass value of `fileName` variable from this function to another 
`protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}` where i save it in the database. but value always is null. Am i doing something wrong or it remain null as functions are defined as `Protected` type

```
public partial class News: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string _fileName = null;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
          // some code here......
         }
     }

protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);

                if (f.Extension.ToLower() == ".pdf" || f.Extension.ToLower() == ".doc" || f.Extension.ToLower() == ".docx")
                {
                    //3MB file size
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 307200)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                        if (!System.IO.File.Exists("../pdf/news/" + FileUploadControl.FileName))
                        {
                            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../pdf/research/") + filename);
                            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                            _fileName = FileUploadControl.FileName;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _fileName = null;
                            StatusLabel.Text = "File with this name already exsists, Please rename file and Upload gain";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _fileName = null;
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 3MB!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _fileName = null;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only PDF or Word files are accepted!";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _fileName = null;
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the value filename should be accessible within the same class. Did you debug your code?

Comment: @mrsrizan, Yes i did debug it, If properly assign value to `fileName`  variable in upload function and when i click the save button their is is always null.

Comment: you should make it static. like,   static string _fileName = null;

Comment: @mrsrizan Oh no, no, *no*, **no**, ***no***!!! This will make the field shared between all users of the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET WebForms doesn't quite work like you expect it to... You have to understand the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Basically, at each request, your page object is recreated from scratch. The two button clicks will generate two requests, and so you'll get two page instances, one for each request. You can't share data between them this way.

You have several ways to overcome this:

- Use the `ViewState` for this. This is an object that is basically serialized, then sent to the client. The client sends it back at each postback, and it's deserialized so you can access it. So do not put sensitive data inside. There are facilities that let you [encrypt this data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx) though.
- Use the `Session`. But this can become messy pretty quick, and you'll have to deal with the case when the user opens serveral instances of the same page.

Comment: you mean `ViewState["_fileName"]` in the file upload event.

Comment: I'd go with the viewstate because of the issues with the session object described in the answer. If you store a relative unpredictable path you're fine. If you store an absolute path I'd either refactor the code to store some kind of token, or encrypt the viewstate.

Comment: I need not worry about encryption as this is part of backend section of applciation used only by limited users... I hope i got your point right.